# Getting all text from Notepad++ document in c++ for Notepad++ plugin

Tags: c++, notepad++, readfile

I am writing a **plugin for notepad++** with visual studio 2013 (C++).

How can I get all text from notepad++ documantation?

There is a `SCI_GETTEXT` function for this. I use `sendMessage` function.(e.g `::SendMessage(curScintilla, SCI_GETTEXT, end, null))`

But this function returns `long` value. Can I convert this long value to `char` or how can I do this in other way?

**SCI_GETTEXT doesn't work without sendMessage funtion.**

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly their documentation You will have to send the `WM_GETTEXT` message to the handle of the editor window, where `wParam` will be the length of text you can accomodate and `lParam` will be the address of the preallocated data. After `SendMessage` returns you are suppsoed to have the data populated.

(I am not familiar with the `SCI_...`stuff , this is the "oldschool" way of solving this problem :) )